# CommandLine GPG: decrypt retaining original filename

Tags: batch-file, gpg4win

I have a batch file that's used to decrypt files to a specific `folder/filename`, but I want to decrypt the file to a specific folder and not change the name, decrypting it from `File090620.csv.gpg` to `File090620.csv`

- Batch file command:

  ```bash
  gpg --no-use-agent --passphrase-file ".\passphrase.txt" --batch -- output ".\dir1" --decrypt "dir2\File090620.csv.gpg"
  ```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put the file path or file name in a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop and then use ***variable substitutions*** referencing only the needed part which is the file name only in GPG format without the extension (e.g. `File090620.csv`) to run the GPG commands.

Furthermore, expanding on this to loop through multiple files in directory if needed is trivial and just a matter of making a few adjustments and testing.

### Command Line

```
For %A in (*.gpg) do gpg --no-use-agent --passphrase-file ".\passphrase.txt" --batch -- output "%~FNA" --decrypt "%A"
```

### Batch Script

```
For %%A in (*.gpg) do gpg --no-use-agent --passphrase-file ".\passphrase.txt" --batch -- output "%%~FNA" --decrypt "%%A"
```

> ### Why this works...
>
> - The variable is set in the code using `FOR %%A` or `FOR %A` for single percent sign if not running in a script. This is the variable
>     placeholder/character set which will reference a single (or iterated) file.
> - The `in (*.gpg)` tells `%A` or `%%A` that it equals the value in the `in (SET)` portion parenthesis which is currently `.\File090620.csv.gpg`in your sample case.
> - Referencing `%%A` with the *for variable substitution* within the command or execution portion of the for loop as `%%~NA` (or
>     `%~NA`) expands the value it's iterating or you set with only the file with no extension which gives the desired result in your case to
>     use accordingly in the looped command.

### Supporting Resources

- [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- `FOR /?`

  > In addition, ***substitution of FOR variable*** references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > ```

Comment: Hi, idiot not understanding what u mean. Basically we get a file every week which will include the date in the file, so will change every week. But there will only be one file in the folder when the script runs. Part of the script empties the folder at the end of the script. So the gpg decrypt part needs to not really care what the file is called, just decrypt it with the name it was delivered in with out the .gpg

Comment: If the script you run is not in the same folder as the gpg files, then use `C:\GPGFolder\Path\*.GPG` rather than `*.GPG` and it'll take care of the rest for the full entire path the GPG file location @JohnVenables

Comment: @JohnVenables Let me know your status once you get to this, you can put the full code you are using on https://pastebin.com/ and then send me a link if you need more code to be fully integrated. Let me know if the latest edit helped you with your task. If not, I think I just need to see all the code you are using to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bat will be saved in the same folder where your `.gpg` files are saved/received.

If the bat is just clicked, it takes the most recent `.gpg` file and decrypts it in the intended folder and exits, making only the last file received.

If a `.gpg` file is dragged and dropped on it, it will describe that file that it received by parameter, also saving it in the intended folder.

Just adjust the variables to the relevant paths:

```bat
@echo off 

set "_path_gpg=D:\Full\Path\To\gpg.exe"
set "_password=D:\Full\Path\To\Password.txt"
set "_output_dir=D:\Full\Path\To\Output\Folder"

if not "%~dpnx1" == "" (
     set "_decripty=%~dpnx1"
    ) else set "_decripty=%~dp0*.gpg"

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /b /a:-d /o-d /tc "%_decripty%"')do (
     "%_path_gpg%" --no-use-agent --passphrase-file "%_password%" --batch --output "%_output_Dir%\%%~ni" --decrypt "%%~fi" 
     "%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /t 10 & goto :EOF
    )
```

---

Use an `if` to handle the file informed by parameter (if informed), and `else`  to define all `*.gpg` files, just to make the `dir` list/get your most recent file on the first run inside the loop and exit.

`Timeout.exe` is just to give you a break and check if there are any other adjustments to be made, if not, you can remove it:

```bat
"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /t 5 &  goto :EOF
```

- If you need the bat to always (and only) decrypt only the last file:

```bat
@echo off 

set "_path_gpg=D:\Full\Path\To\gpg.exe"
set "_password=D:\Full\Path\To\Password.txt"
set "_output_dir=D:\Full\Path\To\Output\Folder"


for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /b /a:-d /o-d /tc "%_decripty%"')do (
     "%_path_gpg%" --no-use-agent --passphrase-file "%_password%" --batch --output "%_output_Dir%\%%~ni" --decrypt "%%~fi" 
     goto :EOF
    )
```

**Obs.:** For a good understanding of the expansion variations of variables in looping, arguments etc ..., I suggest visiting the content linked below, because my English could confuse you, or probably, it is not so clear, forgive me.

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**

  [√] **[Command line parameters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)**

  [√] **[Command line parameters (ss64.com)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)**